# Symfony2 JMSJobQueueBundle Listener implementation

Tags: symfony

I am facing some issue in my listener while implementing JobQueueEvent, here is my my listener class

```
class JobStateChangeListener {

    function onJobStateChange(StateChangeEvent $event) {

        if ($event->getJob()->isFinished()) {
            error_log('Job status is isFinished');
        }

        if ($event->getJob()->isPending()) {
            error_log('Job status is isPending');
        }

        if ($event->getJob()->isFailed()) {
            error_log('Job status is isFailed');
        }

        if ($event->getJob()->isRunning()) {
            error_log('Job status is isRunning');
        }

        if ($event->getJob()->isNew()) {
            error_log('Job status is isNew');
        }
    }
}
```

And here is my service.yml for adding listener

```
services:
    jobeventlistener:
      class: ####\SupportBundle\Listener\JobStateChangeListener
      tags:
            - { name: jms_job_queue.job_state_change , method: onJobStateChange }
```

here is how JMSjobQueueBundle dispatch Event https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSJobQueueBundle/blob/master/Command/RunCommand.php#L182

**Updated**: ISSUE is when i run app/console jms-job-queue:run my listener not error_log written  in onJobStateChange func, it may means is not listening . let me know what i am doing wrong.

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? You did not mention that.

Comment: @P.R.Ribeiro added my issue.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Its Because app/console not find --jms-job-id, you need to change your app/console file just replace use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Console\Application; to use JMS\JobQueueBundle\Console\Application; then it will works fine.